# How to move an Overlay with animation in Openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, animation

I would like to animate a Overlay marker from one coordinate to another with a smooth movement.

In the last Overlay documentation:
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.Overlay.html
there are autoPan & autoPanAnimation options, but it is not working for me as you can see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/q2x4vf6x/2/

If I define the marker without those options the marker changes its position as expected, but without animation:

```
marker_pos = new ol.Overlay({
        element: $('<img id="marker_pos" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_GZzKwf6g1o8/S6xwK6CSghI/AAAAAAAAA98/_iA3r4Ehclk/s1600/marker-green.png">')
        .css({marginTop: '-10px', marginLeft: '-10px', cursor: 'pointer'})
});
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a bug there. Firebug sais `TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.`
You can always do the map pan with animation within your function. like so:

```
// Trying animation here...
setTimeout(function(){
    marker_pos.setPosition(ol.proj.transform([4.9090, 52.3667], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
         var pan = ol.animation.pan({
          source: map.getView().getCenter()
        });
        map.beforeRender(pan);
        // when we set the new location, the map will pan smoothly to it
        map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform([4.9090, 52.3667], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
},1500);
```

check your [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/4bt9zb8w/)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to animate the marker, not the map.

Comment: the `autoPan: true,
     autoPanAnimation: {
            duration: 300
        },` doesnt make a feature animation. It pans the map to the your overlay with animation...... Well, at least it should. For your case check this example http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/feature-animation.html

Comment: Good example. Thanks. I found this too http://www.acuriousanimal.com/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter06_02_markers_overlays.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add class with animation to your overlay:

**overlay js code:**

```
   marker_pos = new ol.Overlay({
            element: ...
            className: 'ol-overlay-container ol-selectable animation_move'
    })
```

**css animation:**

```
.animation_move {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
```

And now each time you call overlay.setPosition(...) it will animate to the new position.